# Visual Studio Datetimepicker

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm working on a program that will add records to an access database once a VB form has been completed. Once stored the information can be searched and printed as needed. I'm having no issues with that.

The problem I'm having is when a Windows 7 computer submits information it changes the format of my DateTimePicker.

Ex. The Data was added using the date Wednesday, April 4, 2018. But on windows 7 if a user were to use the same exact criteria from the DateTimePicker and search by it the field would populate as Wednesday, April 04, 2018. Windows 7 adds a 0 placeholder to the front of what day it is when using the DateTimePicker. Is there a way to set the DateTimePicker in Visual Studio to override how Windows 7 is changing this value?

This is the line where my search adapter pulls information based on the DateTimePicker:
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + ComboBox1.Text + " WHERE Date like '%" & CodeText.Text & "%'", myConnection)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't write an sql command in that way. Use always parameters to avoid sql injection and parsing problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction, I got it working. I don't know why I didn't think of it but I just set the DateTimePicker to a custom format and now it works between Win 10 and Win 7. Thanks!

Also it queries just fine, Steve.